# Where can I read up on the haskell "->" operator?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to read more about haskell's `->` operator. I'm not really clear on how much it blurs the line between special syntax and some sort of type class, and I'd like to do some poking around. Specifically, I've seen things like this:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where ...
```

That have piqued my interest.

However, when I try to search for "haskell arrow" or "haskell function" or "haskell class function", I run into the obvious problems of getting results for `Control.Arrow` or simple type class tutorials.

What is `->` called and where can I read more about it?

Comment: Note: That should be `instance Monad ((->) r)`. `(->)` takes two type arguments, while `Monad` is for types that take only one, so you need to partially apply it first.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`(->)` is often called the "function arrow" or "function type constructor", and while it does have some special syntax, there's not *that* much special about it.

It's essentially an infix type operator. Give it two types, and it gives you the type of functions between those types. Just like `2 + 3` is syntactic sugar for `(+) 2 3`, so is `from -> to` syntactic sugar for `(->) from to`. You can think of it like `Function from to` if the symbols are confusing.

In other words, the instance you mentioned can be read as

```
instance Monad (Function from) where ...
```

which makes it clear that we're talking about functions which take arguments of some arbitrary (but fixed) type. In fact, this monad instance is found in [Control.Monad.Instances](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad-Instances.html) and it is essentially the same as [the Reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html).

Looking at [the source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html), it's really quite simple:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
  return = const
  f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

The trivial values given by `return` ignore the argument, and the `(>>=)` operator distributes the argument `r` to both sides.

It's also interesting to note that in the corresponding `Applicative` instance for functions, `pure` and `(<*>)` correspond to the K and S combinators of [the SKI combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus).

`(->)` is also generalized by the [Arrow type class](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html). An introduction to arrows [can be found here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows).

Finally, note that the symbol `->` also appears in other more or less unrelated parts of the syntax, including lambda abstractions `\x -> ...`, case expressions `case ... of x -> ...`, etc. The reverse symbol `<-` also occurs in several unrelated contexts. Don't confuse those with the function arrow.

Comment: Great answer, as always. One could argue, however, that the -> in lambda expressions is more related to the type operator than one might think. And, of course `(\a -> b) c` is `case c of a -> b` and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

I think it *is* called the arrow. According to "[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/)" :

> -> has only one meaning: it denotes a function that takes an argument of the type on the left and returns a value of the type on the right.

Comment: This is in type signatures, but OP's talking about a function