# Arrow operator in functor instance declarations?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm going through [these](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/) Haskell 'intermediate' exercises, I've made the following instances:

```
class Fluffy f where
  furry :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Fluffy [] where
  furry f [] = []

instance Fluffy Maybe where
  furry f (Just e) = Just (f e)
  furry f (Nothing) = Nothing
```

However, the third question syntax has stumped me:

```
instance Fluffy ((->) t) where
  ...
```

I've read up on the arrow operator and also read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136421/where-can-i-read-up-on-the-haskell-operator) which explains the role  of `(->)` in a Monad instance. However I don't quite understand how `(->)` works in the context of Functors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have:

```
class Fluffy f where
  furry :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

We want to define:

```
instance Fluffy ((->) t) where
  furry = ...
```

This means that in the above instance `furry` should have the type `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` where `f` is `((->) t)`, or in other words:

```
furry :: (a -> b) -> ((->) t) a -> ((->) t) b
```

Just as `((+) 2) 3` is the same as `2 + 3`, `((->) X) Y` is the same as `X -> Y` (it's curried operator application and it even works at the type level):

```
furry :: (a -> b) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> b)
```

We can read the above signature as "*given a function from `a` to `b` and a function from `t` to `a`, return a function from `t` to `b`*".

Now you just have to implement it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

We define the `Functor` instance as such:

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap f g = \a -> f (g a)
    -- Pointfree definition: fmap = (.)
```

That is to say, the `(->)` functor is comparable to a container that can only be 'opened' by getting some value of type `a` and 'opening' the container with it. Any `fmap` is then just changing the value after we 'open' the container. Ie: composing functions.

This is a bit like the `Maybe` functor in that I can apply a function to the value if it exists, but for the `(->)` functor I'm doing that before we know what it is.

But remember that all monads are functors, since we could just define `fmap` as so:

```
fmap f m = m >>= (\a -> return (f a))
```

So if you understand what that would do in the `Monad` instance it should be clear what it does in the `Functor` instance.