# Understanding Haskell's (->)?

Tags: haskell

Few times I saw `(->)` while learning "advanced" Haskell.
`ghci` fails when I try to run `:t (->)`, thought sometimes even official documentation uses this notation.

As far as I can **guess**, `(->)` is an **any** morphism in the **Hask** - basically, any Haskell function. I assume that the idea is to fix either source or target endpoint: for example, `((->) Int)` might mean any function to the `Int` type; obviously, `(Int (->))` means any function from the `Int`.

Next assumption is that `(->)` might be an endofunctor. `fmap` implementation seems pretty trivial: having a fixed endpoint of type `a` and morphism `f :: a -> b` one can produce an instance of the `((->) b)`. It preserves `id`and yet does not tear existing compositions: i.e. `fmap(g . f) = fmap(g) . fmap(f)`.

So my **first question** is: am I right?

My **second question** is why then `:t (->)` fails in the `ghci`?

My **thrid question** is there a way I can use `(->)` in a real Haskell code? Do I need to enable some `{{ #Pragma ...` extension? Or it is just a theoretical notion used to explain concept and nothing more?

And, finally, **last question**. Does dual notion `(<-)` exist?

Comment: Looks like there's some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9136421

Comment: `(->)` isn't a value, so you can't ask for its type. However, you _can_ ask for its kind `:k (->)` or just information about it `:i (->)`. `((->) Int)` means any function _from_ the `Int` type - think about the analogous difference between `((/) 2.0)` and `(/ 2.0)`.

Comment: @Alec, indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`->` is the type constructor for the types of functions. `f :: A -> B` means "`f` is a function from some type `A` to some type `B`".

`:t (->)` is an error because `->` is not a value and does not have a type; it is a type (or rather type constructor). Similarly, `:t Maybe` and `:t Int` are errors.

As with normal operators, infix application is syntactic sugar for (curried) prefix application; i.e. just as `x + y` can be written `(+) x y` or `((+) x) y`, so can `A -> B` be written `(->) A B` or `((->) A) B`.

`((->) Int)` does not mean "any function to the `Int` type"; it's a type constructor for functions *from* `Int`. By itself it is not a valid type, but you can apply it to a type to get a valid function type; e.g. `((->) Int) String` is the type of functions from `Int` to `String`.

`(Int (->))` is a kind error; it tries to apply `Int` to `(->)`, but `Int` does not take any arguments.

`(->) e` is indeed a `Functor` for any type `e` (with `fmap = (.)`, i.e. function composition). It's also an `Applicative` and a `Monad` (it's equivalent to [`Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#g:2)).

All of this is standard Haskell syntax. No language extension is needed.

`<-` does not exist at the type level. It is reserved syntax that can be used in expressions, e.g. in list comprehensions (`[ x * 2 | x <- [0 ..] ]`) or `do` blocks (`do { x <- p; return (x * 2) }`); it's also used in some other contexts, but not in types.

Comment: It seems both `->` and `<-` are reserved and cannot be (re)defined.

Comment: Since `((->) Int) String` is a valid function **type**, `:t ((->) Int) String` should reply with something like `(Int -> String)`, however it keeps failing. While `:k ((->) Int) String` spits out something unexpected: `*` - is it a placeholder meaning literally "whatever might be"?..

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov You can only ask for the type of values, not of types. Types don't have types, they have kinds.

Comment: @melpomene, oh, I got it now.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov `*` is just the kind of regular types. `:k Int` is `*`, `:k Maybe` is `* -> *`, `:k Either` is `* -> * -> *`. Note that `(->)` is both a type constructor and a kind constructor: `:k (->)` is `* -> * -> *`.