# Why define a functor instance for a 'nameless' type like `(->) e`

Tags: haskell, types

In Haskell [GHC base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.htm) has definitions of a Functor instance for a type `(->) r`:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

[Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) explains *`((->) e)` is the type of functions which take a value of type e as a parameter.* This makes sense, but I'm lost how `(->) e` is used later, compared to `Maybe`, `Either a`, even `[]`.

I think I understand these functor definitions, which are named: `Maybe`, `Either a`, but I have a hard time understanding how a 'nameless' type `(->) r` is used.

Does this mean I need to suspect any other `a ->` in every type signature as functor? Is this a way of defining the properties of arrow `->` in Haskell?

Also is this the same arrow as in type signatures or an arrow from lambda functions? I tried looking up in Haskell report, but there `->` is used in own notation for documentation, so no luck there.

Thanks in advance for any hints that can help breaking the ice around `(->) r`.

Update: based on comments I think I should be asking where `->` type constructor defined? is it a built-in?

The answer to that is `->` is built in, and it is a [*"function arrow" or "function type constructor"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136421/where-can-i-read-up-on-the-haskell-operator).

Comment: `(->) r`, is *not* a nameless type. In fact if you write `a -> b`, you wrote `(->) a b`. `(->)` is a type constructor, just like `Maybe`, `Either`, etc. The fact that it is used as an "infix operator" is not that odd. `(:)` for example is a data constructor for a list, and is also used with infix.

Comment: It is anything but nameless. `->` is a name like any other name, just with a funny infix syntax. `((->) r)` is not different from `Either r` in any way.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, thanks! Is there any place to look where `->` is defined, or it is a built-in?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. thanks for the comment! I'm now trying to grasp where is `(->)` defined

Comment: It is a built-in.

Comment: Would a type synonym `type Arr = (->)` help, where functions have the type `not :: Arr Bool Bool` and the instance you mentioned is `instance Functor (Arr a) where fmap :: (b -> b') -> (Arr a b -> Arr a b'); fmap = (.)`?

Comment: @Iceland_jack, actually a type synonym really helps to navigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(->) r` is *not* a nameless type. Its name is `(->)`, just like `Either` is a name. In fact if you write `a -> b`, you wrote `(->) a b`. Or if you write `a -> b -> c`, then the canonical form is `(->) a ((->) b c)`.

`(->)` is a type constructor, just like `Maybe`, `Either`, etc. The fact that it is used as an *infix operator* is not that odd. If you write `x : xs` for example, then the canonical form is `(:) x xs` (or more verbosely `((:) x) xs`). If you enable the `TypeOperators` extension, you can even write types like `` Left 1 :: Int `Either` String ``.

Comment: This part especially useful: ` (->) ((->) a b) c`, I thought if signature can be written this way, and it does!

Comment: From learners perspective one does not think of infix operators on type level, so very helpful to learn, thanks again.

Comment: I think `a -> b -> c` is actually `(->) a ((->) b c)`. It's right-associative.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: yes you are right. Made a mistake :(